# In ArcMap, can polygon labels always be displayed in a fixed area of the screen?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

If I'm inside an area, I want its properties to be displayed in a fixed area of the screen (top right, let's say).

I am talking about data view, and what I mean is that if I'm zooming into a city, for instance, the country, state, zip code, etc. would show in the fixed area even though the boundaries were not actually visible.

Comment: That would be great functionality, but as far as I know that is not possible. I am assuming you are talking about data view, and what you mean is that if you are zooming into a city, for instance, the country, state, zip code, etc. would show in the fixed area even though the boundaries were not actually visible.

Comment: You can create Feature Linked Annotation and move the Annotation to the fixed area of the screen (not map?)

Comment: @MLowry  (Yes, that's what I was talking about)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't differentiate between data view vs. layout view.  If layout is possible, how about using mapbook/data driven pages and linking the attribute data to specifically located text pieces on the layout?

Comment: I want this thing in data view, sorry for not specifying in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If your polygons are relatively the same size and shape you could make a copy of this layer.  Start an edit session on it and select and drag all the features up and to the right a bit.  Next, convert the edited polygon layer into a point layer and just label the point features (you could also make the point symbol null so it looks like the polygons are holding the labels).  Most likely this will not work/look perfectly for all features, but it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Using Feature Linked Annotation (ArcEditor/ArcInfo Licence required)

*"Feature-linked annotation is a special type of geodatabase annotation that is directly linked to features. Feature-linked annotation reflects the current state of features in the geodatabase: it is automatically updated when features are **moved**, edited, or deleted"*

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000pz000000.htm

With the Maplex Extension Text can be manipulated well and in a control manner then  better .Annotation can be created